# Selecting Select Option based on stored mysql value

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have an edit page for user profiles. One option is 'Country' with all the countries listed in the php file (countries are not loaded from database). On the user edit profile page I want to be able to select the currently stored option value from the list.

I could do this:

```
<option value="Afghanistan" <?php if ($results['country'] == 'Afghanistan') echo 'selected';?> >Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Albania" <?php if ($results['country'] == 'Albania') echo 'selected';?> >Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria" <?php if ($results['country'] == 'Algeria') echo 'selected';?> >Algeria</option>
<option value="American Samoa" <?php if ($results['country'] == 'American Samoa') echo 'selected';?> >American Samoa</option>
 // The rest of the countries here :(..
```

Is there a better (cleaner) way to do this without putting all the countries into the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, iterate a `$countries` array using a `foreach` loop, and generate the options, match against the country value to find the selected.

Example:

```
$countries = array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa");

foreach ($countries as $country) {
    echo "<option value='$country'";
    if ($country == $results["country"]) {
        echo " selected";
    }
    echo ">$country</option>\n";
}
```

Outputs (for `$results["country"] = "Albania"`):

```
<option value='Afghanistan'>Afghanistan</option>
<option value='Albania' selected>Albania</option>
<option value='Algeria'>Algeria</option>
<option value='American Samoa'>American Samoa</option>
```

Comment: Thank you this is the correct answer. The other answer is also correct but you were the first to answer! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you want right, I suggest using a `foreach` loop:

```
$countries = array(
    "Afghanistan",
    "Albania",
    "Algeria",
    "American Samoa"
    // ...
);

foreach($countries as $country) {
    echo '<option value="'.$country.'"';
    if($country == $results['country']) {
        echo ' selected="selected"';
    }
    echo '>'.$country.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: you are missing a ' at the end of 1st echo. this should be `echo '<option value="'.$country.'"';`

Comment: @Virendra thank you very much, I was looking at the code highlight and thought something was wrong, but could not see what :)

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is the same as 'Truth' - but he answered first so I selected his for answer. +1

Comment: At first he provided only the first sentence as the answer, so I wrote all the code, but I don't mind.

Comment: Did a bit of modification for the associative array and used it in my code..Worked well

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers if you can't store the countries in a DB you may consider storing them in a text file. Read them in and iterate over them. This will make it easier to add new countries without changing code. Just a thought.

Comment: I am actually in the process of doing that right now! plan to use file() function, just trying to figure out the details right now.

Comment: Why? Make a countries `.php` file and put them in like an array, then all you have to do is `require_once('path/to/countries.php');` and no excess parsing every time you load the page.

Comment: Vlakarados, thats my point. Iwas just trying to keep it generalized regardless of programming language. Just giving the poster a tip.