# Codeigniter PHP getting option value

Tags: forms, codeigniter

I've got a complicated re-population system that works, but it's cumbersome.

I've got a dropdown menu for a country of birth, and when the users submit the form it gets thrown in a database. The dropdown menu then gets repopulated with whatever is in the database if there is something.

I get the value from the database like this:

```
$birthplacecountry = (!set_select('birthplacecountry') && $birth_citizenship) ? $birth_citizenship[0]['birthplacecountry'] : (set_select('birthplacecountry') ? set_select('birthplacecountry') : '');
```

That works fine, as I've then got my options looking like this:

```
<option value="Afganistan" <?php if ($birthplacecountry == 'Afganistan') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Albania" <?php if ($birthplacecountry == 'Albania') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria" <?php if ($birthplacecountry == 'Algeria') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Algeria</option>
<option value="American Samoa" <?php if ($birthplacecountry == 'American Samoa') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>American Samoa</option>
```

However, it's annoying having to compare $birthplacecountry to the name of the value manually. Is there a general way to compare something to the options value?

Some sort of functionality that works like: if ($birthplacecountry == this.option.value)

Comment: Oh wow, there's an identical question already!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133207/selecting-select-option-based-on-stored-mysql-value?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In codeIgniter, you should use [Form helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) to produce a select/dropdown, i.e.

```
$options = array(
    'Afganistan'  => 'Afganistan',
    'Albania'    => 'Albania',
);
echo form_dropdown('birthplacecountry', $options, 'Albania');
```

In this example, a `dropdown` with name `birthplacecountry` will be created and selected `option` will be `Albania`, the seconf one. The third parameter sets the selected `option`, so, when you want to repopulate the form with selected option, you can do something like this

```
echo form_dropdown('birthplacecountry', $options, set_select('birthplacecountry', $this->input->post('birthplacecountry') );
```